# Angularfire2 validate username before creating user

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, angular5

I can't get my head around how queries works in AngularFirestore.

I'm trying to validate a custom username against the users I already have in the database since I don't want users to be able to select the same username. Unfortunately, I fail already here. I'm using this piece of code based on what I have been able to read here and other places.

```
 this.users = this.db.collection('/users', ref => ref.where('team', '==', this.user.team));
```

I'm sorry for being lost and asking what you might consider a basic question. I just can't get my head around why it's not working.

Regards,

Hendrik

Answer (score 0):

I hope i get your question right.
Try this and give me feedback if it's working or not.

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

// your function onclick 
emailcheck($event) {
let x = $event.target.value;
if (x.trim() == '') {
  this.status = 'Email is required';
}
else {
  this.status = 'Loading..'
  let collectionRef = this.afs.collection('users').ref;
  let queryRef = collectionRef.where('email', '==', x);
  queryRef.get().then((snap) => {
    if (snap.empty) {
      this.status = 'OK!';
    }
    else {
      this.status = 'Email already in use!'
    }
  })
}
```

if you user the firebase function createUserWithEmailAndPassword()

```
// register function
register() {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(inputValue.email, inputValue.password)
  .then((success) => 
  // your code after Success 
  )
  .catch((error) => {
    // your code after fail
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log("ErrorCode: " + errorCode + "<br>ErrorMessage: " + errorMessage);
    if(errorCode == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
      // if email already in use
    }
    if(errorCode == 'auth/invalid-email') {
      // if invalid email
    }
  })
}
```